# How to get last values from a log file

Tags: python, python-2.7, extract, logfile

I have a log file, which holds the temperature values.
Using this code I can extract only temperature values from it.

Code:

```
import re
import itertools

infile = "/home/pi/Mysensor/Logs/test.log"
for line in open(infile):
    match = re.search('Temp=(\d+)', line)
    if match:
        test = match.group(1)
        print test
```

My log file:

```
2017-08-04 -> 16:14:29
Temp=28.0*  Humidity=36.0%
```

Code output:

```
28
28
25
29
28
25
```

What I want to do is, just extract only last four results.
I have tried with arrays and list. But could not get a result.

What am I missing here?
How to get this program to get only the final four result?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are your attempts? Can't see them. Using a list sounds promising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the temperatures on a list, and use slices to get the 4 last:

```
import re
import itertools
temps = []
infile = "/home/pi/Mysensor/Logs/test.log"
for line in open(infile):
    match = re.search('Temp=(\d+)', line)
    if match:
      test = match.group(1)
      temps.append(test)
print temps[:-5:-1]
```

To see more about slices, [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-slice-notation)

Answer (score 1):

I guess this really depends on how big your log file is, but there are a couple of ways I can think of to do it.

The easiest is probably to use a `deque`.

```
from collections import deque
import re

temps = deque(maxlen=4)

infile = "/home/pi/Mysensor/Logs/test.log"
with open(infile, "r") as fh:
    for line in fh:
        match = re.search('Temp=(\d+)', line)
        if match:
            temp = match.group(1)
            temps.append(temp)
```

Comment: your answer iterates through, Tisp's answer is giving me the best soulution.

Comment: They both iterate through. They're almost the same code. The only difference is that using a deque means you don't have to keep the whole array in memory. The downside is that you need to do an extra `pop` operation at each stage. Like I said, it depends on how big your file is.

Answer (score 1):

One straightforward approach is to use tail from linux shell

```
  1 import os
  2 
  3 def my_tail(f, n):
  4     stdin, stdout = os.popen2("tail -n " + str(n) + " "+ f)
  5     lines = stdout.readlines();
  6     return lines
  7     
  8 print my_tail("./my_log.txt",4)
```

Comment: It's nice, but assumes that the user isn't on Windows box.

Comment: @VKShopov I m on linux, the output is `['Temp=18.0*  Humidity=36.0%\n', '\n', '2017-08-04 -> 16:14:29\n', 'Temp=28.0*  Humidity=36.0%\n']` , just the last line.

Comment: @Sachith Well there are four '\n' - each of them counts as new line. So it seems that every record of Your data is consisted of several lines.

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay if some other language can do the same you may use the below commands in a bash shell (*assuming the log file name is stack.log*) :

**grep 'Temp' stack.log | tail -4 | gawk -F= '{print $2}' | gawk '{print $1}' | sed s/*//g**

Breaking the above commands :

1. grep 'Temp' stack.log -> search for "Temp" string in given log file.
2. tail -4 -> will extract last 4 records from above commands output.
3. gawk -F= '{print $2}' -> uses "=" as delimiter and print the first column, 
   for example :
   29.0*  Humidity
   21.0*  Humidity
   22.0*  Humidity
   28.0*  Humidity
4. gawk '{print $1}' -> uses"space" as delimiter and print the first column 
   alone, for example :
   29.0*

   21.0*

   22.0*

   28.0*
5. sed s/*//g -> replace all "*" (asterisks) with blank "" (blank).

Final output looks like :

29.0

21.0

22.0

28.0

**You may redirect this to a file and read in your program as temperatures.**

Comment: Awesome, this does the trick. But in the work, I focus on python than shell. Thanks for the answer.